# Why is 'https://www' intermittently hidden in Chrome 69?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl

Whilst browsing the net I have noticed that the URL prefix is mostly always displayed:

```
https://www
```

However I have noticed one just one occasion where this has not appeared, i.e. the omnibox has shown:

```
example.com
```

This has occurred even on the same domain and without changing any settings in Chrome

There are several articles I have read regarding Chrome's phasing out of the `https://www` prefix, however, could there be a reason for this intermittently occurring? If it makes a difference, the only time I have noticed this is whilst browsing 'Incognito'

Additionally, the following article on ZDNet titled “[Chrome 69 kills off www in URLs: Here's why Google's move has made people angry](https://www.zdnet.com/article/chrome-69-kills-off-www-in-urls-heres-why-googles-move-has-made-people-angry/)” explains we should expect not to see the `https://www` prefix anyway, so why am I still seeing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely a combination of things at work:

1. Chrome's default behavior of hiding `http://` for non-HTTPS websites.
2. Chrome's habit of connecting you to the HTTPS version of a website when using auto-complete in Chrome's Omnibox.
3. A website offering both "www" and "non-www" URLs (no redirects)

My guess in how things played out:

1. You reached the HTTPS, www version of a website (e.g., `https://www.example.com/`), maybe through Google search.
2. In follow-up attempts, you might let Chrome auto-complete the URL, leading you to the HTTPS version.
3. In incognito mode, you may have typed out the domain name sans www, leading you to just `example.com`

Compare the following URLs (typed and auto-completed) for the main website of the well-known brand Toys R Us:

https://www.toysrus.com

http://www.toysrus.com

https://toysrus.com

http://toysrus.com

I believe Google's decision to remove www was temporarily reversed for Chrome 69  [as noted by Bleeping Computer](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/chrome-69-shows-the-www-and-m-subdomains-again-but-it-s-only-temporary/). Apparently this change will return with Chrome 70.

Comment: So would this mean that when eventually I was lead to example.com , this would still be the HTTPS bound version of the site?

Comment: @D.M No. If you were on just "example.com", then this is the NON-HTTPS version. Chrome would then show "Not secure" at the beginning of the Omnibox. The HTTPS version will show a padlock and `https:`

Comment: @D.M Could you clarify what you mean by "lead to". My earlier comment assumed you were simply on the website where the Omnibox only shows "example.com", but if you typed "exa" and let Chrome fill in the rest, you will be connected to `https://example.com`, which IS HTTPS.

Comment: If I recall, the order of the events were:
> 1. On the HTTPS site > 2. Clicked the 'home' button in top left of the site > 3. Omnibox displayed simply 'example.com' . I can't remember either way seeing a 'not secure' or a padlock. Could this have been a Man in the Middle exploit?

Comment: @D.M No, if you were originally on the HTTPS version and then clicked on a "home" button on the webpage or other link therein leading to a NON-HTTPS website, this is not a MITM exploit. It may be that the link on the website, for unknown reasons, is pointing to its non-HTTPS version instead, and should be fixed by the website developer / administrator. But I would need the website to confirm.